# Do we have to mention the things we refer to after the word "one of these"

Tags: grammaticality

Do we have to mention the things we refer to after the word "one of these"
For example....

"I have a lot of cars.One of these is BMW"

"I have a lot of cars.One of these cars is BMW"

Which one of the previous phrases is grammatically correct?

Comment: The first is better but you need an article. 'One of these is **a** BMW'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to include [nouns] as in "One of these [nouns]" if it's clear what "these" refers to. Sometimes, even if it's not.

> I have chickens, cars, and houses. One of these is a BMW.
>
> Look at the three closed doors! Behind one of these is a new car! (The other two have goats.)

Comment: How do you like San Diego? ( http://www.bmwbuilders.com/)

Comment: Is the chicken soft top or hard top?

Comment: More seriously: *These* should be *them* in every example here. How important you think the error depends on you.

Comment: @TimLymington Seeing as this was replicated from the OP who was looking for a different part of the statement to be clarified, I would seek dispensation. Otherwise, *One of them cars* would be quite inappropriate. May I interest you in one of these fine comments?

Comment: *Ego te absolvo*. Interestingly, 'one of them cars' would not raise an eyebrow in Northern England, while 'one of these cars' would not be said (in OPs context) by any native speaker I know. And your first example could be reordered so that you could use *one of the latter [or former]*, but there is no good way to avoid ambiguity in the present order. There may be a question there...